# How to upload mysql data to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch.

I am trying to upload my existing MySql data to Elasticsearch. Elasticsearch bulk import uses json as the data format. That's why I converted my data to the json format.

**employee.json:**

```
[{"EmpId":"101", "Name":"John Doe", "Dept":"IT"}
 {"EmpId":"102", "Name":"FooBar", "Dept":"HR"}]
```

But I am not able to upload my data using the following curl command:

```
post: curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_bulk?pretty' --data-binary @employee.json
```

I get a parsing exception message.

After reading a document(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html), I realized that the data format should be something like this:

```
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
....
action_and_meta_data\n
optional_source\n
```

I am still not sure how to format my data in the above format and perform the upload operation.

Basically I want to know the exact data format that is expected by the Elasticsearch bulk upload. And would also like to know whether my curl command is correct.

Comment: Maybe you can use logstash. Check this: https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-jdbc-input-plugin

Comment: @alpert thanks!! But can't I do the same thing with curl command?

Comment: Of course you can. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You data should be in form:

```
// if you want to use emp id as doc id specify otherwise dont add _id part
{ "index" : { "_index" : "index_name", "_type" : "type_name", "_id" : "101" } }
{"EmpId":"101", "Name":"John Doe", "Dept":"IT"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "index_name", "_type" : "type_name", "_id" : "102" } }
{"EmpId":"102", "Name":"FooBar", "Dept":"HR"}
....
```

Or you can use logstash: https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-jdbc-input-plugin

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
{ "delete" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "create" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "3" } }
{ "field1" : "value3" }
{ "update" : {"_id" : "1", "_type" : "type1", "_index" : "index1"} }
{ "doc" : {"field2" : "value2"} }
```

So you would probably want your file to read something like

```
{ "update" : {"_id" : "101", "_type" : "foo", "_index" : "bar"} }
{"EmpId":"101", "Name":"John Doe", "Dept":"IT"}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html